# Read/Write not working on external sd card - Android

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, permissions, storage, external-sd

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 and no applications can read or write to the external SD card - except the Root Browser. This happened a month or so ago after I installed a custom ROM (Alliance) and I have lived without access to the external SD card since.

Since then, an application has managed to create one folder on the card that is accessible to a regular file manager (such as ES File Explorer).

When I use my PC to access the SD card, all is fine and visible, so I have deduced that it must be something in the android config files. I have checked 
/system/etc/permissions/platform.xml 
and I have
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

`<group gid="media_rw" />
<group gid="sdcard_rw" />`

WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE

`<group gid="media_rw" />`

Comment: I should mention that I have tried different micro sd cards and the problem is exactly the same.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?